# Collection Method within Rails Model gets error NoMethodError: undefined method `collect'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having trouble applying a method to a collection within a model. Here's what my model looks like:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.range(min, max)
    where(id: min..max)
  end

  def self.my_collection_method
    collect{|x| x.id}
  end
end
```

This works:

```
MyModel.range(53, 55)
# [#<MyModel id: 53>, #<MyModel id: 54>]
```

And this works:

```
MyModel.range(53, 55).collect{|x| x.id}
# [53, 54]
```

But when I try to be fancy and use *my_collection_method* instead of *collect*, I get this error:

```
MyModel.range(53, 55).my_collection_method
# NoMethodError: undefined method `collect' for #<Class:0x007fcbad3efc30>
```

How can I get this to work?

Thanks for your time and wisdom!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you're trying to achieve but you should be able to use it when you call scoped first

```
def self.my_collection_method
  scoped.collect {|x| x.id}
end
```

without `scoped`, you are trying to call `self.collect` which is not a method of `ActiveRecord` models.  having `scoped` there means you want to apply `collect` to the current chain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!! I'm still having trouble understanding scoped.

I tried adding `scope : my_collection_method, lambda { |x| x. id }` but it didn't work when I ran `MyModel.range(53, 55).my_collection_method`. Why does `scoped.collect` work (ie. why do we put `scoped.collect` inside the function)?

Comment: I just read [13.3 Working with scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-scopes) and it says that `.scoped` returns an "ActiveRecord::Relation object which can have further scoping applied to it afterwards." Does this mean that all collection methods, such as map, collect, each, applied within a model method have to be "scoped" first? And what the heck does scoped mean anyway? Forgive my frustration, but I can't find a clear definition for this anywhere.

Comment: Ok, I'm spamming my own thread here, but I think I've got a working answer from [this asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough). "Having queries return an ActiveRecord::Relation object allows us to chain queries together." I guess I was attempting to chain queries together with `MyModel.range(53, 55).my_collection_method`. Please correct me if I'm wrong, and if anyone has some intuition about this concept, please chime in!

Comment: yep you are right. updated my answer on why using scoped works :)

Answer (score 2):

You've defined `my_collection_method` on the model, not on a collection - they are separate classes. You can normally achieve what you want to do inside a model method:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.range(min, max)
    where(id: min..max)
  end

  def self.my_collection_method(min, max)
    range(min, max).collect{|x| x.id}
  end
end
```

The only other way is by attaching a method on the fly to the collection, but that's going to be pretty ugly.

Comment: Thanks for you help @Jonathan, this is a valid approach too